# When I run my while loop, nothing shows up

Tags: c#

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.Design;
using System.Threading.Channels;

namespace IfStatements
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int counter = 0;
            string enteredText = "";
            while (enteredText.Equals(""));
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Please press enter to increase amount by 1," +
                    " and anything else if you want to finish counting.");
                enteredText = Console.ReadLine();

                counter++;
                Console.WriteLine("Current count of people inside is {0}", counter);
                Console.Read()
           }
       }
    }
}
```

This code worked in the video I was watching but not for me (I'm a beginner and taking a course).

Comment: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: The code, as you posted it won't compile let alone run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just Remove `;` from the end of the while loop ...

```
  // while (enteredText.Equals("")); 
   while (enteredText.Equals(""))
```

Answer (score -2):

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int counter = 0;
        string enteredText = "";

        while (enteredText.Equals(""))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Please press enter to increase amount by 1," 
+
                " and anything else if you want to finish counting.");
            enteredText = Console.ReadLine();

            counter++;
            Console.WriteLine("Current count of people inside is {0}", 
counter);
            Console.Read();
        }
    }
}
```

The while loop condition is not set up properly. The semicolon after while (enteredText.Equals("")) should be removed, and the loop should be enclosed within curly braces {}. There's a stray using System; at the end of the code. This should be removed or placed at the beginning of the file.

Comment: That comment should probably be part of the answer, right? You can edit your answer any time with the grey button on the bottom left.

Comment: When there is a difference of just a single character between your code and the original, then please point it out *inside* your answer.